# Is there any reason not to declare all my variables in one go?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a moderately complex VBA programme with a lot of variables to keep track of in a bunch of nested subs. I've done this by having one module called "Variables" with all my variables (except those declared in sub declarations or dim:ed as loop counters) declared as Public, all neatly categorised and commented.

It all works nicely and the code runs quickly, but the fact that sample code I find hardly ever uses Public/Private and tends to default to Dim gives me a nasty suspicion I'm doing something wrong.

Is there a real downside to doing them all in one big bunch, or am I just paranoid?

Comment: A question from programmers.stackexchange provides an excellent answer: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Comment: There's a whole bunch of terminology in that one that's all Greek to me, but I think I got the gist.  It looks like I'll have to stick with Public to be able to use the variables between modules - I don't suppose there's anything between Public and Private to limit them to within one project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a fan of Globals. You can get into state problems. Additionally you can't set break points in Globals.

Although, nothing is cast in stone, since every situation is different, what I would suggest is:

1. In modules, declare subs and functions private unless accessed outside the module.
2. In Classes, declare everything as private unless required. Where you need to expose fields, use properties.
3. Inside functions and subs, declare everything inside the routine as opposed to globals.
4. Declare all parameters as ByVal unless you have a reason to pass ByRef.

I only use globals where necessary. Sometimes you do need to use them but I have to justify it to myself. I've supported numerous workbooks that use globals which are set with event handlers in sheets, users buttons etc. which can give you headaches in debugging.

Hope that helps.